# How to re-install Software Center?

Tags: installation, software-center, uninstall

I've had a problem with Software Center for a few weeks, where it has just refused to delete a removed PPA from its "All Software" and "Installed Software" drop-down menus. I've tried many suggested solutions, none have worked, so I've finally decided to re-install Software Center if its possible. How do you do this and is it risky to your computer (i.e. will re-installing it cause all sorts of issues)?

Comment: In similar questions regarding PPA removal, I've seen `ppa-purge` package recommended (and marked as an answer). Have your tried it?

Comment: Yep, already done all of that, trust me. This is my last resort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reinstall the **Software Center** with a fresh start to all its systemwide configuration files by issuing this command in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
```

(You can copy that whole thing to the clipboard, paste it into the Terminal, and press enter. If you enter it manually--which I recommend against--then please take note to only press enter at the end; there is no line break in the middle, it's just too long to be displayed on one line.)

That command is written so that it also completely reinstalls the packages that provide the **Software Sources** window, which is at least as likely to be responsible for any problems relating to disabling a PPA as is the **Software Center** itself.

Comment: So all I have to do is copy and paste the code you gave above and it'll re-install Software Center, right? Will it remove the custom PPAs that I currently have in my Software Sources, like ones for various dev builds for programs and that sort of thing?

Comment: @Icedrake Pasting the command from my answer that starts with `sudo` and ends with `-gtk` will do that, yes, but that will *not*, by itself, result in the configured software sources (including PPA's) being changed in any way. I've edited my post to include more details about this. @WarriorIng64 I've also edited my post to include information about this method of making pasted text into a code block--thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code fixed the problems that I was having, after nothing else could for so long. Thank you!