# How do I reinstall the Software Center?

Tags: installation, software-center, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to re-install Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79987/how-to-re-install-software-center)

I've somehow accidentally uninstalled Software Center and I can't seem to reinstall it. I don't have a web browser currently on the computer, as I uninstalled Firefox to get Chrome, and didn't install Chrome before my Software Center disappeared.

When I search  "software center", it comes up in the *Apps Available for Download* section, but nothing seems to work for installing it. I click it repeatedly and nothing happens, and when I drag it into my home window it just opens the file. Help, anyone?

Comment: It's possible the software center is just failing to launch due to some bug... that unfortunately happens sometimes.Try entering `software-center --debug` into a terminal, if you could.

Answer (score 1):

Open the *Terminal* application and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

You will be prompted for your user password.

Answer (score 0):

There is the on-line version of the Ubuntu Software Center: [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/)