# I accidentaly removed ubuntu software centre

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to re-install Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79987/how-to-re-install-software-center)

It seems that i accidentaly un-installed ubuntu software centre.I relly want to re-install it but i don`t know how.Can someone help me?